# Why is my drop down list showing old values instead of null?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# .NET web program which has dropdown lists of manufacturers and models of cars. Whenever you click on a manufacturer it should give you their models. The list for the models is binding fine as long as the manufacturer in question has many models. Once I click a manufacturer that has no models in the models database table, the Models dropdown list still keeps the values for the previous manufacturer instead of binding null and clearing the dropdown list options for the manufacturer with no models. 
The function in question is shown below:

```
public void BindModels(int manufacturer)
{
    int numberOfModels;
    string strConnectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString); // Connect to Carsales database
    conn.Open();                            // Select all models for a particular make
    string com = "SELECT ModelID, ModelName From VehiclesModels Where ManufacturerID = " + manufacturer + "  ";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn);// Convert the database string to an sqldata adapter
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();      // Create a data table for binding
    numberOfModels = adpt.Fill(dt);      // Determine number of models for this manufacturer before binding
    if (numberOfModels > 0)               // Fill the data table with the open Sql connection
    {                                    // If models exist for this manufacturer
        drpModel.DataSource = dt;        // dropdownlist data source is newly created table
        drpModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"; // relate database fields to dropdownlist fields
        drpModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";  // Model ID goes in the value field
        drpModel.DataBind();                  // Data bind to the dropdown list in the front end
        //hdnModelID.Value = "0";             // Indicate an unselected model exists
        if (numberOfModels == 1)              // If only one model (Special case)
        {
          BindGrid4BodyDetails(Convert.ToInt32(drpModel.SelectedValue)); // Bind the grid for body details for this model
        }
        hdnModelID.Value = drpModel.SelectedValue; // Indicate the only possible selection as the current ModelId value
    }
    else
    {                                // If no models exist for this manufacturer
        hdnModelID.Value = "-1";     // Indicate this via hdnModelID value
        drpModel.DataSource = null;  // Bind null to the models to indicate no models
        drpModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"; // relate database fields to dropdownlist fields
        drpModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";  // Model ID goes in the value field
        drpModel.DataBind();         // and clear any previous model data bound
    }
    conn.Close();             // Close the connection to the carsales database
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong inside the else statement? Why is it not binding null to the drop down list? Any help will be appreciated and the correct answer rewarded. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly clearing the dropdown list by calling drpModel.Items.Clear() ?

Comment: I have now Adrian. Do you mind posting this as an answer below so I can give you some points? It worked.

Comment: I can but before I do, do you mind trying to remove the numberOfModels > 0 condition and the else case, so that the datasource is always set to dt? If there are no records in the datasource, nothing should get binded to the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `drpModel.Items.Clear();` will explicity clear your items, but you shouldn't have to do this. You should be able to always bind the DataTable `dt` to the dropdown, even when there are no items in the result set. In this case, the DropDownList control will simply contain no items.

Change your code to the following:

```
public void BindModels(int manufacturer)
{
    int numberOfModels;
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString); 
    conn.Open();                            
    string com = "SELECT ModelID, ModelName From VehiclesModels Where ManufacturerID = " + manufacturer + "  ";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();      
    numberOfModels = adpt.Fill(dt);      

    // set the DataTable as the DataSource, no items will be added to the DropDownList control if the DataTable has no records
    drpModel.DataSource = dt;               
    drpModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"; 
    drpModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";  
    drpModel.DataBind();                  

    if (numberOfModels == 1)              
    {
        BindGrid4BodyDetails(Convert.ToInt32(drpModel.SelectedValue)); 
    }
    hdnModelID.Value = drpModel.SelectedValue; 

    conn.Close();             
}
```

Comment: You are a champion. What more can I say??

Answer (score 0):

How about this to go even one better: (One from the Baby Master):

```
public void BindModels(int manufacturer)
{
    int numberOfModels;
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString2"].ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);  // Connect to Carsales database
    conn.Open();                                   // Select all models for a particular make
    string com = "SELECT ModelID, ModelName From VehiclesModels Where ManufacturerID = " + manufacturer + "  ";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, conn); // Convert the database string to an sqldata adapter
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();            // Create a data table for binding
    numberOfModels = adpt.Fill(dt);// Determine number of models for this manufacturer before binding
                                       // Fill the data table with the open Sql connection
    drpModel.DataSource = dt;          // dropdownlist data source is newly created table
    drpModel.DataTextField = "ModelName"; // relate database fields to dropdownlist fields
    drpModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";  // Model ID goes in the value field
    drpModel.DataBind();                  // Data bind to the dropdown list in the front end
    switch (numberOfModels)
    {
        case 0: hdnModelID.Value = "-1";   // If no models exist for this manufacturer, Indicate this via hdnModelID value
                txtMessage.Text = "No models exist for this manufacturer"; // Give user a message.
                break;
        case 1 : BindGrid4BodyDetails(Convert.ToInt32(drpModel.SelectedValue)); // If only one model (Special case)
                                         // Bind the grid for body details for this model
                 hdnModelID.Value = drpModel.SelectedValue;  // Indicate the only possible selection as the current ModelId value
                 break;
        default : break;
    }
    conn.Close();                   // Close the connection to the carsales database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)               
   {                                     
     drpModel.DataSource = dt;         
     drpModel.DataTextField = "ModelName";  
     drpModel.DataValueField = "ModelID";   
     drpModel.DataBind();  
   }
```

Comment: This way does not work. It gives me an Invalid Operation Exception:

Comment: Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.